# Broken search for anything tagged with [swift-language]

Tags: bug

The search seems to be broken when looking for anything containing the [swift-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-language) tag. For example [Search for reflection in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift-language%5D%20reflection) produces no links.

However, at least two entries for this exist:

- [Reflection (introspection) in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112911/reflection-introspection-in-swift?noredirect=1#comment37198750_24112911)
- [Does Swift support reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060667/does-swift-support-reflection)

Comment: Comments in similar questions suggest that due to an ongoing data migration searches only return historic results from before approx June 2nd. It's not just limited to Swift but since that is a very new tag it's very obvious there.